# URL rewrite with HTTPS / www not working for subpages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, typo3

I have to following configuration in my .htaccess. The first rule puts https before the URL and the second puts www before the URL, if not set already.

```
# https redirect
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# www redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

These redirects work perfect for the homepage. However, if you call a subpage, these rules wont work.

```
domain.xy -> https://www.domain.xy (works, Homepage)
domain.xy/contact -> http://domain.xy/contact (doesnt work)
```

The weird thing is, the favicon get redirected correctly. Example with the contact page, as seen on
[this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxSS0.png)

How can it be, that my configuration only works for the toplevel, not for any subpage?

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for detailed post(keep it up). Could you please do let us know if you see any errors in logs etc(because looking wise your Rules look fine to me)?

Comment: You will need to debug yourself: open the development console in your browser. Use a fresh anonymous browser for this test to prevent caching issues. Make a request and monitor what redirections the browser actually receives back. That way you can narrow down the issue. Most likely this is "just" a caching issue. In general: always use a 302-redirection while you are still trying around. Only change that to a 301 once you are convinced your setup is final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was another rule in the .htaccess-File. Our hosting provider automatically generates a .htaccess suiting the Typo3 installation. I had to place my rewrite rule before the following lines:

```
# If the file/symlink/directory does not exist => Redirect to index.php.
# For httpd.conf, you need to prefix each '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}' with '%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}'.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:CWD}index.php [QSA,L]
```

This rules, as far as i understand, redirects any request, which is not a file, directory or symlink back to the `index.php`. So in my case if i call `domain.xy/contact`, it redirects back to the `index.php`.

Because this rule has the `[L]` flag at the end, the .htaccess stops processing here. So i moved both my rules above this block and they get called before this block comes to action.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your `RewriteRule` is wrong. It should be `.*` instead of `^`:

```
# https redirect
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# www redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: `^` just matches the beginning of a string, so it should always match. The problem was a other rule from a basic Typo3 .htaccess-File. Those Typo3-Rules were automaticly set by the provider. See my answer.